# User Control instead of Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a StackPanel with a few buttons that contain images.
It works perfectly so far, but my question is, is it worthy of creating a user control for the button or should I use it as is with the StackPanel?

```
<StackPanel>
<Button>
    <Image>
      ...
    </Image>
</Button>
<Button>
    <Image>
       ...
    </Image>
</Button>
<Button>
    <Image>
      ...
    </Image>
</Button>
```

And the suggested User Control should be :

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControlToolButton}}}">
<Button x:Name="ButtonBase" Command="{Binding Click}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
    <Image x:Name="ImageButton" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding SourceBase}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding SourceMouseOver, TargetNullValue=SourceBase}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

Comment: Honestly I don't see any needs of a UserControl here... With a proper Style / Template what you want to do can be achieved easily and more cleaner than a UserControl. If you want to Style all Buttons in the StackPanel you can enforce that by adding the Style in the Stackpanel`s resources.

Comment: Or by adding Style for all Buttons into the App.xaml's file.

Comment: Yes... But you can inherit from your Button Style in app.xaml if you want all buttons that is the child of StackPanel to have that style. That way you dont have to explicitly define the style on each button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an [ItemsControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?view=netcore-3.1) with an `ItemTemplate`, you could define the `Button` inline without using a `UserControl` or repeat yourself:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="...">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button ...>
                <Image ...>
                    <Image.Style>
                        ...
                    </Image.Style>
                </Image>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If not, you should probably create a `UserControl` in order to not having to define the same markup repeatedly. Or a `Style`.

Comment: Actually, I make a Style for all Buttons and add it to the App.xaml file